# Prime profile settings issue: Which one should I choose from the below prime profiles for software development purposes?

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, lubuntu, power-management, performance

There are three options in Prime Profiles:

1. NVIDIA (Performance Mode),
2. NVIDIA On-Demand,
3. Intel (Power-saving mode).

The Ubuntu 20.04 battery is draining too fast. If I choose Intel(Power-saving mode), the NVIDIA graphics will function or not. If it will not work, then it may be affected for Machine Learning related projects.

Comment: Is there are question; your 'question' is written as a statement.   *Please note the title of your question may not be readable for all devices/readers of the site; so any details in your title should also appear in your actual question.. where currently you state "There are 3 options.. " with a question mark on the 3rd item, but no actual question*.

Comment: @guiverc There is a question. If you look at [the markdown source for the question](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/196676f4-f785-4d8c-92b1-3cd0cb6e65ce/view-source), there was meant to be a line break before the final question. So the question would be "Which one should I choose for software development purpose?" which is opinionated.

Comment: Can anyone answer?

Comment: I currently use mine on On-Demand so that my graphics card is only used when I'm running something that is graphic intensive such as playing a game or rendering something.

Comment: @ParthShah Ok thanks. Let me try. But is it helpful for improving the battery performance?

Comment: @PKS21 Definitely since the integrated GPU is used for most stuff and the power-hungry GPU is only used when you need it.

Comment: @ParthShah yeah it helped thanks.